# Drag folder into Eclipse IDE?

Tags: php, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, textmate

I was just wondering if anyone knows the way to use Eclipse IDE without creating a project?

So I could just open folder and use Eclipse just like a regular text editor?

Just like notepad++ or textmate?

by using plugins maybe?

Thanks

P.S> damn - the only thing that I miss in Ubuntu is my Notepad++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything in Eclipse is done in projects.  There's no way around that.  Just create a general purpose project which you always have open.

Comment: Exactly. Projects are a very basic concept in Eclipse and since you want to debug something there really is no way around creating a project.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't answer the question but i'd recommend using Geany. Its lightweight, supports syntax highlighting for many languages and many other capabilities.
Thats what i use as a replacement for notepad++ on linux.

Comment: Thnaks. I've tried it. Unfortunately I need PHP debugger. it's a dealbreaker to me. Notepad++ has it, geany doesn't as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse you simply do File > Open File...

Also you can use [notepad++ in Ubuntu with WINE](http://flannelbum.posterous.com/howto-notepad-on-ubuntu-jaunty-via-wine).

Comment: yeah - I know. tried it and it's not quite the same. tabs change slower and it's crashy.:(

Answer (score 1):

You can try Kate in kubuntu :)

Comment: hm :) Tried DBG,etc?


Reference links :    
> http://protoeditor.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=tutorial
> http://www.php-debugger.com/dbg/installation.php